# Separation of variables for $tu_t = u_{xx} + 2u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Separate the variables for the equation
$$tu_t = u_{xx} + 2u$$
with the boundary conditions
$u(0,t) = u(π,t) = 0$.

Show that there are an inﬁnite number of solutions which satisfy the initial condition $u(x,0) = 0$. Explain qualitatively the reason for this.

---

Seek solution of form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. We can rewrite the main equation as $$\frac tT \frac{dT}{dt}= \frac1X \frac{d^2 X}{dx^2}+2 = \lambda$$

$u(0,t)=0=X(0)T(t)=0$, for all $t$ $\implies$ $X(0)=0$

$u(\pi,t)=0=X(\pi)T(t)=0$, for all $t$ $\implies$ $X(\pi)=0$

The problem for $X(x)$ is: $$\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} +(2- \lambda )X=0$$

---

On the solutions of this question, it says "To satisfy the homogeneous boundary conditions we must have $X$ in the form of sines and cosines and therefore $λ < 2$. "

But if $2- \lambda =0$, we have $X=Ax+B$ and using the conditions of $X(0)=X(\pi)=0 \implies X(x)=0$. This satisfies the initial condition given.

I didn't bother to consider when $\lambda >2$ after reading that in the solutions. Why do we not consider when $\lambda =2$ or $\lambda >2$? They seem to work out or the initial condition.

Is it because the questions asks about infinite solutions and the only way that is possible is if we have sines and cosines involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\lambda>2$, the general solution is
$$X=c_1\cosh\sqrt{\lambda-2}x+c_2\sinh\sqrt{\lambda-2}x$$
At $x=0$, the boundary condition says that
$$X(0)=0=c_1$$
And at $x=\pi$, we have
$$X(\pi)=0=c_2\sinh\pi$$
So $c_2=0$ and we have only the trivial solution $X(x)=0$.

If $\lambda=0$, the general solution is
$$X=c_1+c_2x$$
At $x=0$ the boundary condition is
$$X(0)=0=c_1$$
While at $x=\pi$, again we see that
$$x(\pi)=0=c_2\pi$$
So again only the trivial solution. That's how we know that $\lambda<2$.

**EDIT**: Then if $\lambda<2$, the general solution is
$$X=c_1\cos\sqrt{2-\lambda}x+c_2\sin\sqrt{2-\lambda}x$$
At $x=0$, again
$$X(0)=c_1=0$$
And at $x=\pi$.
$$X(\pi)=0=c_2\sin\sqrt{2-\lambda}\pi=\sin n\pi$$
Thus $\lambda_n=2-n^2$ and
$$X_n(x)=\sin nx$$

Comment: So we cant have trivial solutions? Why is that?

Comment: Well, you can have them, but superposition of $0$ with other solutions doesn't affect the outcome because $0$ is the identity element under addition of the field of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, why is X not $X_n=B_n \sin(nx)$ instead of what you wrote? How does the constant B just disappear.

Comment: Don't worry, it will come back after you establish that $$T_n(t)=\frac1{t^{n^2-2}}$$ and then $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nT_n(t)X_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n\sin nx}{t^{n^2-2}}$$

Comment: BTW, hope you noticed that imposing the condition $u(x,0)=0$ means that your solution will just be $u(x,t)=c_1t\sin x$.